# Pulling data from RSS using JQUERY

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, rss

**Objective:**
Pulling data from an RSS feed and display up to 5 data entries at a time.

**Issue:**
URL for reference: https://www.goughrecruitment.com/t/ella-toohey

The current issue is when the data is increased more than 5 entries the browser will display an error message of "Stopped scripting".

**Code:**
JavaScript:

```
if( $('#jobList-sector.consultant-job-posting').length ){
       var candidateJobList = $('#jobList-sector.consultant-job-posting').data('url');
       if( candidateJobList.trim() != '' ){
           //candidateJobList = candidateJobList + '&addlocation=1&addworktype=1]';
           $("#jobList-sector.consultant-job-posting").addClass('loading');
           $("#jobList-sector.consultant-job-posting").includeFeed({
               baseSettings: {
                   rssURL: [candidateJobList || "/job/rss.aspx"],
                   limit: 5

               },

               templates: {
                       itemTemplate: '<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6"><div class="white-bg"><header class="jobpost-head"><time>{{pubDate}}</time>'+
                       '<h3><a href="{{link}}" title="{{title}}">{{title}}</a></h3></header>'+
                       '<div class="jobpost-desc">{{description}}</div></div></div>'
                   },




               complete: function () {
                   if ($(this).children().length ){
                       if( $(window).width() > 767 )   {
                           $(this).children().children().equalHeights();
                       }
                   }else{
                       $(this).append('<p>No job posted yet!</p>');
                       $(this).parent().find('.btn').remove();
                   }
                   $(this).removeClass('loading');
               }
           });


       }else{
           $('.current-positions, .consultant-link-wrapper .view-all-jobs').hide();
       }
   }
```

Comment: Without knowing where `includeFeed` comes from it's hard for anyone to help. Issue would be related to that plugin

Comment: The version of include feed is include-feed-3.0.js. For reference, I will update the page URL with the issue within the description. URL is: https://www.goughrecruitment.com/t/ella-toohey

Comment: Thanks for your assistance.

Comment: That doesn't tell anyone where that plugin comes from.

Comment: The plugin is coming from our own server, not a CDN.

Comment: Where file itself is served from is irrelevant...the source and docs are what count

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115354/discussion-between-andrew-c-duarte-and-charlietfl).